# Change gridview image on click with camera/gallery intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm new to android development and I'm trying to create a gridview with 4 static images that when one of them is clicked triggers an intent for the user to choose a picture or take it, then replace the thumbnail in the gridview item they just clicked with the new image but I'm stuck on the actual part of it returning the image back to the gridview and it knowing which position.

I've searched around but I can't seem to find an answer for my specific issue. Hope someone can help explain what is missing and why or how I can achieve this thanks

Here's my code that I've got and I've tried to include the position as a putextra in the intent:

ImageAdapter.java

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;


public ImageAdapter(Context c ) {
    mContext = c;

}

public int getCount() {
    return defaults.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return defaults[position];
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);

        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(
                (int)mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.width),
                (int) mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.height)));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

   imageView.setImageResource(defaults[position]);


    return imageView;
}

// references to our images
private Integer[] defaults = {
        R.drawable.cameraicon,  R.drawable.cameraicon,  R.drawable.cameraicon,  R.drawable.cameraicon
};
```

claimantdetails_activity.xml

```
 <TextView android:id="@+id/add_photos_header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="top|start"
        android:text="@string/add_photos_subheader"
        style="@style/subHeaderStyle" />

    <RelativeLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/thumbsGridView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numColumns="4"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:horizontalSpacing="4dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        >

    </GridView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

ClaimFormActivity.java

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mResultReceiver = new AddressResultReceiver(new Handler());

    setContentView(R.layout.claimantdetails_activity);
    SharedPreferences ClaimantDetails = getSharedPreferences("claimant_details", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


    DateEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.DatePicked);
    TextView editTime = (TextView) findViewById((R.id.TimePicked));

     addressLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AccidentLocation);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.thumbsGridView);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

   gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                                               int position, long id) {
selectPhoto(position);         
}
});
public void selectPhoto(final int position) {

    final CharSequence items[] = new CharSequence[]{"Take Photo", "Choose from Library"};
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ClaimFormActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {


            if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                //   userChosenTask="Take Photo";

                //once option chosen check and show permissions
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ClaimFormActivity.this,
                        Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ClaimFormActivity.this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                            CAMERA_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);
                } else {

                    cameraIntent(position);

                }
            } else if (items[item].equals("Choose from Library")) {

                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ClaimFormActivity.this,
                        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ClaimFormActivity.this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                            GALLERY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);
                } else {
                    galleryIntent();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}

private void cameraIntent(int position) {

   Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra("id", position);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);

    }
}
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    final LocationSettingsStates states = LocationSettingsStates.fromIntent(data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CAMERA:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                handlePicture(data);

                break;
            }
}
 public void handlePicture(Intent data) {

    Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);

    //save image to phone

    File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
    FileOutputStream fo;

    try {
        destination.createNewFile();
        fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        fo.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't find the code of updating adapter after you clicked the picture. is it missing or you forget to upload ?

Comment: @dex thats part of the piece I can't really work out, i tried adding this to the end  of handle picture but it didn't like it so I'm not really sure what else to put    `mGridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.thumbsGridView);
mGridView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);`